# Is there anyway to grant my app the READ_VOICEMAIL permission on a rooted phone?

Tags: android, android-permissions, root

I have an app that needs to be able to read all the voicemail on the device, which requires the `com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL` permission. It's a system-level permission, and I can't figure out a way to grant that permission to my app.

I already had my app successfully get root access, and I can run commands as "su", but when I try to run `pm grant com.my.app com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL`, I still get an error. Is there anyway to get this done?

Alternatively, I know that moving my app to the `/system/priv-app/MyApp/MyApp.apk` should solve this problem, but I'm having issues doing that on Android 13. I tried doing it on LineageOS 20, and after rebooting, it would boot-loop  (until I started in Recovery, and manually deleted the APK from the system partition). There used to be a Magisk module called App Systemizer that would do this cleanly, but it's my understanding that it no longer works on Android 12 or 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know how to do this using any root commands, but I figured out how to properly move my app to `/system/priv-app`, which automatically gives it all system permissions.

In addition to just moving the APK there, you need to also create a permissions file with your app package name in `/system/etc/permissions`. Here's an example of my **com.my.app.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<permissions>
    <privapp-permissions package="com.my.app">
        <permission name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL"/>
        <permission name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL"/>
        <permission name="com.android.voicemail.permission.WRITE_VOICEMAIL"/>
    </privapp-permissions>
</permissions>
```